if (isset($_POST['submit'])) is not working/always is empty
Here's my code, the only thing possible that wouldn't work is the isset for posting additem which name ive changed:
<?php
// Check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['additem']))
{
    // Database connection parameters
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root"; // Default username for XAMPP MySQL
    $password = ""; // Default password for XAMPP MySQL
    $dbname = "POS"; // Name of your database

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Retrieve form data
    $itemId = $_POST['itemId'];
    $itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
    $itemPrice = $_POST['itemPrice'];
    $itemTab = $_POST['itemTab'];

    // Prepare and bind SQL statement
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO items (ItemID, ItemName, ItemPrice, ItemTab) VALUES ('$itemId', '$itemName', '$itemPrice', '$itemTab')");

    // Execute the statement
    if ($query) {
        echo "<script>alert('Item added successfully')</script>"; // Corrected syntax
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Error')</script>"; // Corrected syntax
    }

    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Item List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Item List</h1>
    <form method="post" action="" id="itemForm">
        <label for="ID">ID:</label>
        <input type="number" id="ID" name="itemId" required>
        <label for="itemName">Item Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="itemName" name="itemName" required>
        <label for="itemPrice">Price:</label>
        <input type="number" id="itemPrice" name="itemPrice" required>
        <label for="itemTab">Tab:</label>
        <input type="text" id="itemTab" name="itemTab" required>
        <button type="submit" name="additem" value="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <table id="itemTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Tab</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Items will be dynamically added here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

I've looked at the whole code over and the only issue it wont pass the isset post. Help!

Are you using JavaScript to submit the form instead of default form submission?

whoa i just disconnected the JavaScript and it started working again, there was an event listener that was probably causing issues for that form, Thank you! But how would i still be able to use JS or no? the php only works with the JS script removed

The JS needs to send the additem parameter in the post data. It's not sent automatically when you serialize the form, but that function doesn't know which button was used to submit.

You could also use if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) instead of checking for the submit button.

I have an issue now that calling my JS ' ' now doesnt link the js file back to the webpage. I'm using the  ' if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) ' method too.

Use the Network tab of DevTools to see whether the form is being submitted and what the result is.
